# phpとvim、文字エンコードについてです。vim初心者です。

Tags: php, vim

多段接続で
.phpファイルをいじっていましたが文字エンコードがsjisのため、文字化けしておりましたので文字エンコードをshift-jisに変えたところエディタのソース側では日本語が¿¿¿¿¿と表示されブラウザで日本語がｿﾂｿﾂｿﾂｿﾂｿﾂｿﾂと表示されてしまいます。

エンコードをなににかえてもうんともすんともいわず困っております。原因がわかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Viで下記で開き直せばみえるとおもいますよ
:e ++enc=文字コード

Comment: 文字コードを一度保存してしまったのが原因でした。。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

sjisということなのでおそらくwindowsだとは思いますがVimは文字化けの問題でるとかなりハマるのでサクラエディタかterapadのソフトを利用して文字コード変換した方がよいと思います。

サクラエディタかterapadで変換してもうまくいかない場合はphp.iniファイルの設定などを確認しましょう。

Comment: 文字コードを一度保存してしまったのが原因でした。。ありがとうございました